# Recreate Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

This is pretty basic, but my question is:

Given an array:

```
$a = array(
0 => array('Rate'=> array('type_id'=>1, 'name' => 'Rate_1', 'type'=>'day','value'=>10)),
1 => array('Rate'=> array('type_id'=>1, 'name' => 'Rate_2', 'type'=>'night','value'=>8)),
2 => array('Rate'=> array('type_id'=>2, 'name' => 'Rate_3', 'type'=>'day','value'=>7)),
3 => array('Rate'=> array('type_id'=>2, 'name' => 'Rate_4', 'type'=>'nigh','value'=>16)),
4 => array('Rate'=> array('type_id'=>3, 'name' => 'Rate_5', 'type'=>'day','value'=>10))
);
```

What is the most efficient way to change it so we have something like:

```
$new_array = array(
   [type_id] => array(
      [type] => array(
          [value]
          )
       )
    )
);
```

In other words, I would like to strip some data (the name, which I don't need) and reorganise the dimensions of the array. In the end I would have an array which I would be able to access the values by **$new_array['type_id']['type']['value']**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is exactly what you want, but with this you can access the values by saying

`echo $new[TYPE_ID][DAY_OR_NIGHT];`

```
$new = array();

foreach($a AS $b){
    $c = $b['Rate'];
    $new[$c['type_id']][$c['type']] = $c['value'];
}
```

Using `print_r` on `$new` would give you:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 10
            [night] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => 7
            [night] => 16
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [day] => 10
        )

)
```

Comment: Amazing how impressively easy you made this look! I am just not sure whether this would be the most efficient way to do it. Looping through all the elements seems a bit unnecessary. I thought we could use some of the built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since php 5.3.0, array_reduce() allows using an array as the initial value, given your initial array $a, you can use the following code

```
function my_reducer ($result, $item) {

    $result[$item['Rate']['type_id']][$item['Rate']['type']] = $item['Rate']['value'];

    return $result;
}

$assoc_arr = array_reduce($a, 'my_reducer', array());
var_dump($assoc_arr);
```

This returns

```
array(3) {   [1]=>   array(2) {
    ["day"]=>
    int(10)
    ["night"]=>
    int(8)   }   [2]=>   array(2) {
    ["day"]=>
    int(7)
    ["nigh"]=>
    int(16)   }   [3]=>   array(1) {
    ["day"]=>
    int(10)   } }
```